# list comprehension with multiple for loops gives NameError

Tags: python

```
l=[1,2,24,3234,4,5,565]
on = [3234]

print [v for v in l[i] for i in range(len(l)) if v in on]
```

Here I get, 
NameError: name 'i' is not defined

Comment: What do you actually want to do ? and the variable v is define twice

Comment: I'm just trying to understand why it's giving error with such syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need to do the inner loop:

```
[v for v in l if v in on]
```

Comment: ikr, I was mistaken about inner list concept in list comprehension, which jeff cleared.
actually the real code is
`trip = [v for v in trip_obj[i].order_data['vehicle_no'] for i in range(0,len(trip_obj)) if v in ongoing_vehicles]`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use "in" you need to define an inner list:

```
print [v for v in [l[i] for i in range(len(l))] if v in on] # [3234]
```

Comment: My answer is directly to your question, you should heed MSeifert's answer as well.